# Testing Catalyst URI's

Tags: perl, testing, catalyst

I am writing a test suite for an application (Utilizing Test::Class::Moose; Catalyst::Test) and have run into a bit of a snag. I have a test that checks that I get a successful response from the URL and then checks the title. Most of the tests pass, but a few URI's are redirecting to a login page. IE:

If I pass /foo/bar, I get the title I expect

```
                but
```

If I pass /foo/baz, it redirects to the login page. '

(In both cases I get a successful response : 200, and the authentication requirements are identical )

My question is: How does Catalyst::Test deal with user authentication and why would it pass authentication checks on some URI's and not others? The documentation is extremely vague in this regard and Dr. Google isn't returning anything helpful either.

Note: The code isn't 'Mine' so I can't post it, but I can give abstract examples if needed.

Comment: Can you at least post snippets of how you are setting up your authentication credentials for the tests, and where the authentication checks are being make on the URI's that are redirecting. That would be of some help towards an answer.

Comment: The thing is that I am not setting up any authentication. I simply invoke Catalyst::Test and perform a request on the uri. I actually did some digging and in auto, no page is being authenticated through the tests. Auto (the app authentication) is redirecting to login at all times, but for some reason I only get a redirected response on some of the pages not all...

Comment: The information in the answer still applies. You need to set up authentication information in your test requests. The link at the end may give some insight into why some of your paths are behaving differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Catalyst::Test](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aTest) the [request](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aTest#res-request) method may be of use to you where your URI's require Authentication credentials.

This method can take a [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) object which allows you to set up the request information beyond a URI string. Most notably as shown in the synopsis, you will want to set up the user agent to support passing in the credentials and cover things like persisting cookies which is the likely session state implementation.

See [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) for more information on this.

As to your questions considering why some URI's require authentication and some don't, it depends on how things are set up in code. Even if there is a general call to authenticate in the `begin` or `auto` action in the Root controller, the dispatch process may be overridden. Taking some time to digest the following may apply.

[Introduction to Catalyst: Built-in actions in controllers/autochaining](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Manual/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Built-in-actions-in-controllers-autochaining)

Comment: I am using the request method already. I have also tried switching it up to ctx_request as well to no avail. I will look into auto-chaining and see how that applies. I was under the impression that Catalyst::Test was overriding the authentication in some way and was surprised to see anything when I warned in auto. In code, everything requires authentication so it shouldn't be localized to this uri... Thanks!!